# Как узнать, за что дали секретные шляпы?

Tags: поддержка, новогодние-шляпы

Собственно, набрал охапку шляп, часть из них секретные. А как узнать, за что они?

- I Am Your Father
  спросите, ответьте или проголосуйте на Мете
- 011
  соберите 11 шляп
- Snaphat
  ответьте в течение 30 минут после публикации вопроса, набрав рейтинг +3, получив отметку принятого ответа
- Fiery
  опубликуйте пять ответов, каждый из которых получит рейтинг более 3
- Abominable
  участвуйте в успешном закрытии или удалении вопроса
- Just Here for the Hat
  получите любое количество шляп пока сообщество суммарно не открыло 20 различных видов шляп
- Bûche de Noël
  спросите, ответьте или проголосуйте 25го декабря
- I Have A Little Dreidel
  спросите, ответьте или проголосуйте в любой день Хануки (24 декабря – 1 января)
- No Longer Grinchy
  примите участие в успешном повторном открытии или восстановлении вопроса
- Where in the World?
  это секретная шляпа
- Blue in the Face
  это секретная шляпа
- 6
  это секретная шляпа
- Trendsetter
  это секретная шляпа
- Don't Wanna Taco 'Bout it
  это секретная шляпа
- The Hatter
  это секретная шляпа
- This Is Fine
  это секретная шляпа

Comment: никак :-) есть чат в котором обсуждение было за что могут дать

Comment: @Grundy, было бы логично, чтобы тот, кто получил, мог видеть, за что.

Comment: Тогда бы он сразу рассказал всем остальным и шляпы перестали бы быть секретными :-)

Comment: @Qwertiy тогда была бы вероятность, что он растрындит это остальным. А это не по правилам

Comment: Хотя, так или иначе, описание все же добавляют в http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288271/winter-bash-2016-all-hats  при массовой утечке

Comment: @АлексейШиманский эти описания добавляет кто попало и там часто появлялась непроверенная инфа

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка но в целом в 90% проверенная) просто надо уметь ждать, а не сразу бежать фармить)